# Why does my rmarkdown/papaja not suppress following author names when i have already cited it multiple times (as it would be required APA style)?

Tags: r-markdown, bibtex, citations, papaja

I am so sorry for asking, but i have been unable to find a solution (and i've tried hard).
When i add a @author syntax in my rmarkdown script (corresponding to my created bib.file) and knit the file the authors are cited correctly.
But when i cite the authors the next time it does not do author et al. (year) but displays all authors again!
I have already tried loading other publkic available .rmd and .bib files (that have appropriate citations) but when i knit them myself, the same problem appears.
How can i fix this?

I would really appreciate any advices, thanks in advance! <3

Edit:
For example, a BibTex entry would look like this:

```
@article{Zygar-Hoffmann2018,author = {Zygar-Hoffmann, Caroline and Hagemeyer, Birk and Pusch, Sebastian and Sch{\"{o}}nbrodt, Felix D.}, doi = {10.1002/per.2145}, journal = {European Journal of Personality}, number = {3}, pages = {306--324},title = {{From Motive Dispositions to States to Outcomes: An Intensive Experience Sampling Study on Communal Motivational Dynamics in Couples}}, volume = {32}, year = {2018} }.
```

An in my rmarkdown (papaja template) text i write:

The influence of rather stable motives on behavior is proposed to be (fully) mediated by the current motivation [@Zygar-Hoffmann2018].
The latter describes a varying state that results from an individual’s motive, the current situation and their interaction [@Zygar-Hoffmann2018].

Now i would expect that when knitting the second citation appeared as "Zygar et al. (2018)" but unfortunately it doesn't.
I have the latest Version of R, RStudio, MacTex and Mac OS Big Sur installed.

Comment: Hi Hanna, could you provide a minimal reproducible example? I'd be happy to take a closer look.

Comment: Yeah for sure! I am sorry, i am new here and not quite familiar how to upload scripts or anything, i tried to copy my code/text in the question as an edit. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I also get this same behavior when I use `pdf_document()` and specify the latest version of the APA6 CSL file manually. This tells me that it is a more general problem with `citeproc` or the current version of the APA6 CSL file. For the time being, you could switch to using `biblatex` instead by using the following YAML header:

```yaml
bibliography      : references.bib
biblio-style      : "apa"

output:
  papaja::apa6_pdf:
    citation_package: biblatex
```

**Update**: [This problem has been fixed](https://github.com/jgm/citeproc/issues/60). Updating `pandoc` and `citeproc`, or waiting for RStudio to ship the new version of `citeproc` should resolve the problem.