# Papaja does not use "et al." when citing a reference more than once in apa format

Tags: r-markdown, bibtex, citations, papaja

When I knit the R-Markdown file for the APA-styled document, I saw that "et al" is not used in the output pdf file, instead the author names were not suppressed but written each time. I found the answer to this problem for pdf outputs here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66453232/16082436

```
bibliography      : references.bib
biblio-style      : "apa"

output:
  papaja::apa6_pdf:
    citation_package: biblatex
```

Unfortunately, this solution does not work for word outputs. Can you help me to fix this problem in word documents as well?
When I used papaja 2 years ago, there was not such a problem.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a recent bug that I hope we will be able to address soon. However, there is a workaround: `papaja` relies on Citation Style Language CSL, and therefore, you can manually download the `apa.csl` file from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/citation-style-language/styles/master/apa.csl) and put it in the same directory as your `.rmd` file. You can then include the CSL file via this additional line in the YAML header of your document:

```
csl: apa.csl # "et al." did not work
```

In my document, this solved the problem, and "et al." was properly used in both pdf and word output.